# R - find rows with at least n distinct elements

Tags: r

I have a data frame of arbitrary but non-trivial size. Each entry has one of three distinct values 0, 1, or 2  randomly distributed. For example:

```
col.1 col.2 col.3 col.4 ...
0     0     1     0     ...
0     2     2     1     ...
2     2     2     2     ...
0     0     0     0     ...
0     1     1     1     ...
...   ...   ...   ...   ...
```

My goal is to remove any row that only contains one unique element or to select only those rows with at least two distinct elements. Originally I selected those rows where the row mean was a not a whole number, but I realized that could eliminate rows containing equal amounts of 0 and 2 which I want to keep.

My current thought process is to use unique on each row of the data frame, followed by length to determine how many unique elements each contains but I can't seem to get the syntax right. I'm looking for something like this

```
DataFrame[length(unique(DataFrame)) != 1, ]
```

Comment: For sure a dupe out there, but you could use `rowSums(d == d[ , 1]) == ncol(d)` to find rows where all values are equal. Negate to "select only those rows with at least two distinct elements".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try any of these:

```
nuniq <- function(x) length(unique(x))
subset(dd, apply(dd, 1, nuniq) >= 2)

subset(dd, apply(dd, 1, sd) > 0)

subset(dd, apply(dd[-1] != dd[[1]], 1, any))

subset(dd, rowSums(dd[-1] != dd[[1]]) > 0)

subset(dd, lengths(lapply(as.data.frame(t(dd)), unique)) >= 2)

subset(dd, lengths(apply(dd, 1, table)) >= 2)

# nuniq is from above
subset(dd, tapply(as.matrix(dd), row(dd), nuniq) >= 2)
```

giving:

```
  col.1 col.2 col.3 col.4
1     0     0     1     0
2     0     2     2     1
5     0     1     1     1
```

### Alternatives to nuniq

In the above `nuniq` could be replaced with any of these:

```
function(x) nlevels(factor(x))

function(x) sum(!duplicated(x))

funtion(x) length(table(x))

dplyr::n_distinct
```

### Note

`dd` in reproducible form is:

```
dd <- structure(list(col.1 = c(0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L), col.2 = c(0L, 2L, 
2L, 0L, 1L), col.3 = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 1L), col.4 = c(0L, 1L, 
2L, 0L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this:

```
# some fake data
df<-data.frame(col1 = c(2,2,1,1),
col2 = c(1,0,2,0),col3 = c(0,0,0,0))
      col1 col2 col3
1    2    1    0
2    2    0    0
3    1    2    0
4    1    0    0

# first we can convert 0 to NA
df[df == 0] <- NA

# a function that calculates the length of uniques, not counting NA as levels
fun <- function(x){
                   res <-  unique(x[!is.na(x)])
                   length(res)
                  }

# apply it: not counting na, we can use 2 as threshold
df <- df[apply(df,1,fun)>=2,]

# convert the na to 0 as original
df[is.na(df)] <- 0
df
  col1 col2 col3
1    2    1    0
3    1    2    0
```